# PrimeFaces Datatable sticky header inside dialog

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

Stickyheader works in pages, I have a datatable inside a dialog which has more than 100 rows, user has to scroll down

```
<p:dialog>

    <p:datatable stickyHeader="true" >
     ..
     ..
     ..
    </p:datatable>

</p:dialog>
```

I need to enable fixed columnheaders for the datatable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

stickyHeader="true" won't work inside a dialog, finally i found an alternative solution to this

```
<p:dialog>

    <p:datatable scrollable="true" scrollHeight="150" >
     ..
     ..
     ..
    </p:datatable>

</p:dialog>
```

This worked well for me

Answer (score 0):

Scrollable is something different than Sticky Header, but if you need your dataTable to behave exactly like primeface's Sticky Header, you can use [this](http://mkoryak.github.io/floatThead/) feature.
Here jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/1360/ is an easy example how to use it.